# How to fix video size and font wrap for different web browsers

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox, microsoft-edge

**Problem**: There is a tiny different between the video's container and the video height on Chrome, Firefox, and Edge. Additionally, the word wrapping next to the img thumbnails is adding extra space between the two lines.

Screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nbgsm.png

```css
/* Video player CSS */
#video_player {
  display: table;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: #000;
  max-width: 1140px !important;
  max-height: 360px !important;
}

#firstvideo {
  height: 100%;
}

#firstvideo #wistia-khpjv95u1u-1 {
  height: 450px !important;
  width: 800px !important;
  overflow-y: hidden !important;
}

#video_player #wistia-khpjv95u1u-1, #video_player #figcaption {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: top;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

#video_player #figcaption {
  border: 2px solid #9aacd5;
  border-left: 0px;
}

#video_player #figcaption a:nth-of-type(7) {
  border-bottom: none;
}

#vidcontainer {
  height: 360px;
  width: 303px;
}

#video_player #figcaption a {
  display: flex;
  font-size: 14px; 
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e3e5eb;
  color: #000000;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 12px 12px 13px 12px;
}

#figcaption a:hover {
  background: #E3E5EB;
  color: #000000 !important;
}
#figcaption a:focus {
  background: #406acb;
  color: white !important;
}

.wistia_bento_item_name {
  vertical-align: top;
  font-family: Arial;
  padding-left: 2%;
}

#video_player #figcaption::-webkit-scrollbar-track
{
-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: #F5F5F5;
}
#video_player #figcaption::-webkit-scrollbar
{
  width: 8px;
  background-color: #F5F5F5;
}
#video_player #figcaption::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb
{
  border-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
  background-color: #c1daec;
}

/* Firefox (any) */
@-moz-document url-prefix() {
 #vidcontainer {
  height: 450px !important;
  overflow-y: scroll !important;
 }
 .wistia_bento_item_thumb {
  height: 60px;
  width: 100px;
 }
  #video_player #figcaption a  {
  font-size: 12px !important;
 }
}

/* Firefox (newest) */
@-moz-document url-prefix() {
 @supports (animation: calc(0s)) {
 #vidcontainer {
   height: 450px !important;
   overflow-y: scroll !important;
  }
  .wistia_bento_item_thumb {
   height: 60px;
   width: 100px;
  }
   #video_player #figcaption a  {
   font-size: 12px !important;
  }
 }
}

/* Chrome & Safari */
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) { 
    #vidcontainer {
  height: 450px !important;
  }
 .wistia_bento_item_thumb {
  height: 60px !important;
  width: 100px !important;
 }
  #video_player #figcaption a  {
  font-size: 12px !important;
 }
}

/* Internet Explorer */
_:-ms-fullscreen, :root .ie11up {
 #vidcontainer {
  height: 450px !important;
  overflow-y: scroll !important;
  }
 .wistia_bento_item_thumb {
  height: 60px !important;
  width: 100px !important;
 }
 #video_player #figcaption a  {
  font-size: 12px !important;
 }
}

/* Microsoft Edge */
@supports (-ms-ime-align:auto) {
 .wistia_bento_item_thumb {
  height: 60px !important;
  width: 100px !important;
 }
}
```

```html
<div id="video_player">
 <div id="firstvideo">
      <div class="wistia_embed wistia_async_khpjv95u1u playlistLinks=auto"></div>
 </div>
  <div id="figcaption">
    <div id="vidcontainer">
      <a href="#wistia_khpjv95u1u"><img class="wistia_bento_item_thumb" src="https://embed-ssl.wistia.com/deliveries/5e9af872d0c0b2c36a90b650175f270eb8e3a306.jpg?&image_crop_resized=100x60" width="100" alt="The Future of Company Tickets"><span class="wistia_bento_item_name">The Future of Company Tickets</span></a>

      <a href="#wistia_rcyldd4352"><img class="wistia_bento_item_thumb" src="https://embed-ssl.wistia.com/deliveries/56111fc6eed70ca28114e4a993b60a0b98919fc2.jpg?&image_crop_resized=100x60" width="100" alt="Company Tickets & the New Tax Law"><span class="wistia_bento_item_name">Company Tickets & the New Tax Law</span></a>

      <a href="#wistia_wo1fhqfjpf"><img class="wistia_bento_item_thumb" src="https://embed-ssl.wistia.com/deliveries/a804723abfe40dc8d08c68a40720d1b665048a2d.jpg?&image_crop_resized=100x60" width="100" alt="How Anheuser-Busch Measures Sponsorship ROI"><span class="wistia_bento_item_name">How Anheuser-Busch Measures Sponsorship ROI</span></a>

      <a href="#wistia_jq9vslkedz"><img class="wistia_bento_item_thumb" src="https://embed-ssl.wistia.com/deliveries/fbc60cb44f6460c81a761fe37cb667b46f4f1602.jpg?&image_crop_resized=100x60" width="100" alt="How CDW Makes Every Ticket Count"><span class="wistia_bento_item_name">How CDW Makes Every Ticket Count</span></a>

      <a href="#wistia_qyx5135wzh"><img class="wistia_bento_item_thumb" src="https://embed-ssl.wistia.com/deliveries/5293578ec9cd1793fc03ff7aef2ddcfba996e7ed.jpg?&image_crop_resized=100x60" width="100" alt="Providing the ROI of Company Sports Tickets"><span class="wistia_bento_item_name">Providing the ROI of Company Sports Tickets</span></a>

      <a href="#wistia_qdmez6tsor"><img class="wistia_bento_item_thumb" src="https://embed-ssl.wistia.com/deliveries/0e6c3548db9d6f27e5b482f19ededf230f6f2b01.jpg?&image_crop_resized=100x60" width="100" alt="Putting your Tickets in Salesforce"><span class="wistia_bento_item_name">Putting your Tickets in Salesforce</span></a>

      <a href="#wistia_4j36xyw6cl"><img class="wistia_bento_item_thumb" src="https://embed-ssl.wistia.com/deliveries/15cbe0b7232cb132c8ebf79c2e19b928db4ebe92.jpg?&image_crop_resized=100x60" width="100" alt="Building Your Own Ticket App"><span class="wistia_bento_item_name">Building Your Own Ticket App</span></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Prior to adding the media queries, the spacing was fine, but I can't see where the issue is now. Can anyone help?

Comment: Which browser, if any, handles it correctly (per your expectations)?

Comment: @TylerH - I fixed the video's height issue (black line underneath), but am still having trouble with the img thumbnails size, and the text wrapping next to it. The text wrapping issue happens on every browser (Chrome, Firefox, Edge, and IE), but the img thumbnails failing to maintain their proper size only happens on Edge & IE.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed line-height issue by adding line-height: 16px to #video_player #figcaption a:

```css
#video_player #figcaption a {
  display: flex !important;
  font-size: 12px !important; 
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e3e5eb;
  color: #000000;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 12px 12px 13px 12px;
  line-height: 16px !important;
}
```

Fixed video height issue by increasing video height:

```css
@media (min-width: 1024px) {
  #wistia-khpjv95u1u-1 {
    height: 100% !important;
  }
  #wistia-khpjv95u1u-1 > div {
    height: 454px !important;
  }
  #wistia-khpjv95u1u-1 > div > * {
    height: 454px !important;
  }
}
```